# How can I write the equation of this graph?

Tags: systems-of-equations, graphing-functions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yKd8.jpg)

These are points on the graph, so can we write a equation for the graph?

A(0,30), B(10,52), C(20,38), D(30,0), E(40,-37), F(50,-53)

Comment: It's not a very good solution but since you have 6 points you could say the graph is y=ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f then plug in your points.

Comment: You can take a piecewise function.

Comment: Is it a trig function?  Polynomial?  Need some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is in the form

$$ y = A \cos \left( 2 \pi x/ \lambda  - \phi\right ) $$

or in degrees

$$ y = A \cos \left( 360 x/ \lambda  - \phi \, 180/ \pi\right) $$

it requires only 3 points.By least squares best fit can be found.

$$ A= 53 , \lambda= 80, \phi = 20^0  $$